# Regular outlet inside named outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Component `TwoComponent` is displayed inside a regular `router-outlet` and has named `router-outlet` inside its template. I'm using the following code to display child routes (in a manner similar how it's used with `regular outlets`), but it doesn't work.

```
 { 
    path: 'two', 
    component: TwoComponent, 
    outlet: 'named',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child',
        component: TwoChildComponent       
      }
    ]
  }
```

Please, check out this plunkr https://embed.plnkr.co/m1zkHVIfIvDzL6a5PfBB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should work for you

```
[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { named: 'two/child' } }]"
```

Just remove square brackets.

Updated **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NxwWwWOUWv1RI8cthY0F?p=preview)**

Comment: I can't express how greatful I'm to you! Thank you, good sir! I love  you!